# Why would a Scripting language be made 'purposefully Turing non-complete'?

Tags: scripting, programming-languages, bitcoin, turing-machines, turing-complete

So, I was reading about Bitcoin Script on their official documentation and found this line: "**Script is simple, stack-based, and processed from left to right. It is *purposefully not Turing-complete*, with no loops.**" I tried to reason hard but couldn't understand why would someone make a language "***purposefully non Turing-complete***". What is the reason for this? What happens if a language become Turing Complete? 
And extending further, whether "**with no loops**" has anything to do with the script being non-Turing Complete?

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know the reason for down voting.

Comment: You might have been downvoted because your question might be too broad for Stack Overflow, or primarily opinion-based, which would make it off-topic  according to the official guidelines. The best questions on Stack Overflow are ones that ask a single question and have one or a small handful of objectively correct answers.

Answer (score 5):

possible reasons:

- security: if there is no loops program will always terminate. user can't hang up the interpreter. if, in addition there is a limit on size of the script you can have pretty restrictive time constraints. another example of a language without loops is google queries. if google allowed loops in , users would be able to kill their servers
- simplicity: no loops make language much easier to read and write by non-programmers
- no need: if there is no business need for it then why bother?

Comment: I wonder if it's still possible to overflow the stack of this script's interpreter ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is because Bitcoin scripts are executed by all miners when processing/validating transactions, and we don't want them to get stuck in an infinite loop.
Another reason is that according to this [message](http://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/mailman/message/30479316/) from Mike Hearn, Bitcoin script was an afterthought of Satoshi to try to incorporate a few types of transactions he had had in mind. This might explain the fact that it is not so well designed and and has little expressiveness.

[Ethereum](https://ethereum.org/) has a different approach by allowing arbitrary loops but making the user pay for execution steps.